# How can I play a special time range of an audio in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, mvvm, streaming, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I have an activity which streams an audio, the user can (let's say) go backward and forward in the audio with two control buttons. something like this:

[the controls can seek 10 seconds forward or 10 seconds backward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KArXd.png)

How can I implement this with Exoplayer?

Answer (score 0):

exoplayer provides [PlayerControlView](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerControlView.html) ui component. For your case you can customize if needs